# Accessing Class / Union Data in "Column-Major" Format C++

Tags: c++, opengl, matrix, directx, unions

Recently I've learned about the Union storage specifier for data types - it's particularly for OpenGL / DirectX transformation matrix use, since I don't want to keep using the deprecated gluLookAt, gluOrtho, and various MatrixStack functions of the fixed-function pipeline. It's been fantastic, and I recently had lots of fun creating the 4x4 basic Transformation Matrix Class whose internal data is union-packed to allow different ways of accessing the data within the Matrix. The problem is when I want to create a way of aggregating / accessing the data by its columns, without having to make some weird

```
float* Column(int index);
```

function. I know C++ stores its data in row-major form, so how do I provide column access? There's ??? in my below matrix data declaration as to where I'm lost.

```
//#define ROW_EFFIN_MAJOR
union {
    struct {
#ifdef ROW_EFFIN_MAJOR
// Eat one of several nasty things, OpenGL :|
        float m11, m12, m13, m14,
                m21, m22, m23, m24,
                m31, m32, m33, m34,
                m41, m42, m43, m44;
#else
        float m11, m21, m31, m41,
                m12, m22, m32, m42,
                m13, m23, m33, m43,
                m14, m24, m34, m44;
#endif
    };
    float m[16];
    // Use at your own risk: m[1] COLUMNMAJOR is not the same as m[1] ROWMAJOR
    // Rows!
    union MatrixRow {
        struct {
            float r1, r2, r3, r4;
        };
        float r[4];
    } row[4];
    // .... Columns...?
    union MatrixColumn {
        // TODO:
        // Set Union
        // Column Access ?
        // ???
        // Profit
    } col[???];
};
```

Any advice, tips, tricks, or even help would be nice. Ideally, I'd like to access the colums by col[0].c1, or just col[0].c (c being a float[4] of the whole column). However, if this ideal is to be slain for the greater justice of column access (though, leaning towards not-a-function, because I can do it with a special struct and a function. It's just less convenient and a little slower than accessing the data directly via a data member).

I've spent a fair amount of time trying to bash this with google-fu, but I can't figure out how to make a non-contiguous union.

Comment: C++ has no concept of a major dimension, since it lacks the concept of a multidimensional array. It does support the notion of an array of arrays, but whether you call the inner arrays columns or rows is largely up to you. It is more common to refer to them as rows, because they generally correspond to lines of source code when initialising them, but that's purely incidental.

Comment: @WTP Union abuse, huh? I don't see it as abuse, especially when it allows me to not only create my own debugger visualizer using the MatrixRow union, but also access four sequential data elements and group them without having to start pointer jumping. Once I finish making my `union Vector4,`, it'll get even more fun. :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out by Marcelo, C++ is neither row-major nor column-major. It is exactly and only what you put into it. If you call the first four values in a `float` array a "column", it's fine with that. If you call it a "row", it's fine with that too.

In general, you should not switch back and forth between conventions. Don't develop structs that can do "both"; just pick a side and stick with it. If you make your matrices row-major, then they're row-major. When you upload them to OpenGL, you can either manually transpose them or just pass `GL_TRUE` for the "transpose" parameter of [`glUniformMatrix`](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man3/xhtml/glUniform.xml).

More details [are available](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/18901/can-someone-explain-the-reasons-for-the-implications-of-colum-vs-row-major-in/18929#18929).

Comment: Well, thanks for answering. I kind of knew I wouldn't be able to span the data in a "skip four floats" way, but it was worth asking just to make sure I guess. I'll make yours as the answer for now, but I'm going to still sincerely hope that I may be able to get around it someday.

Comment: Though, as a quick side-question: wouldn't giving true to the glUniformMatrix for every single matrix you pass be a bit slower, because OpenGL will have to transpose your Matrix everytime? I mean, it's technically just 6 SWAP commands to transpose the matrix, but...